# Light client ipc blocks

Tags: go-ethereum, light-clients

I tried light client 1.6.0 (a master branch pull). Starting it, it commenced to download block headers. But even if the block header reached the latest block number, when I use `geth attach` and write anything starting with `eth`, the client just hangs.

It also hangs with release/1.5, but here nothing is downloaded at all:

```
 $ geth --light --verbosity 5
 I0320 03:55:14.775222 accounts/keystore/account_cache.go:228] reloaded keys, cache has 2 accounts
 I0320 03:55:14.775916 accounts/keystore/account_cache.go:228] reloaded keys, cache has 2 accounts
 I0320 03:55:14.776585 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/lash/.ethereum/geth/lightchaindata
 I0320 03:55:14.827540 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:/home/lash/.ethereum/geth/lightchaindata
 I0320 03:55:14.828539 node/node.go:176] instance: Geth/v1.5.9-stable/linux/go1.6.2
 I0320 03:55:14.828614 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/lash/.ethereum/geth/lightchaindata
 I0320 03:55:14.846816 light/lightchain.go:120] Added trusted CHT for mainnet
 I0320 03:55:14.847088 light/lightchain.go:172] Last header: #3379462 [c78a082b…] TD=171956396220725049396
 I0320 03:55:14.847529 les/handler.go:202] LES: create downloader
 I0320 03:55:14.847876 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1474] Quality of service: rtt 20s, conf 1.000, ttl 1m0s
 I0320 03:55:14.848082 p2p/server.go:340] Starting Server
 I0320 03:55:14.852248 p2p/discv5/net.go:700] seed node (age 413882h55m14.852228837s): enode://0cc5f5ffb5d9098c8b8c62325f3797f56509bff942704687b6530992ac706e2cb946b90a34f1f19548cd3c7baccbcaea354531e5983c7d1bc0dee16ce4b6440b@40.118.3.223:30305
 I0320 03:55:14.852908 p2p/discv5/net.go:700] seed node (age 413882h55m14.852886742s): enode://1c7a64d76c0334b0418c004af2f67c50e36a3be60b5e4790bdac0439d21603469a85fad36f2473c9a80eb043ae60936df905fa28f1ff614c3e5dc34f15dcd2dc@40.118.3.223:30308
 I0320 03:55:14.853256 p2p/discv5/net.go:700] seed node (age 413882h55m14.853247765s): enode://85c85d7143ae8bb96924f2b54f1b3e70d8c4d367af305325d30a61385a432f247d2c75c45c6b4a60335060d072d7f5b35dd1d4c45f76941f62a4f83b6e75daaf@40.118.3.223:30309
 I0320 03:55:14.854025 les/backend.go:191] WARNING: light client mode is an experimental feature
 I0320 03:55:14.854049 p2p/server.go:608] Listening on [::]:30303
 I0320 03:55:14.854687 les/serverpool.go:466] loaded server stats ccdb466173274add  fails: 0  connStats: 0.3139125280573429 / 18.79367180496  delayStats: 9.138µs / 25  responseStats: 462.287942ms / 34  timeoutStats: 0.9392857142857143 / 560
 I0320 03:55:14.854794 les/serverpool.go:466] loaded server stats 158f8aab45f6d19c  fails: 0  connStats: 0.31794501577540857 / 19.789514924323335  delayStats: 4.101µs / 16  responseStats: 0 / 1  timeoutStats: 0.9230769230769231 / 13
 I0320 03:55:14.854832 les/serverpool.go:466] loaded server stats 78de8a0916848093  fails: 0  connStats: 0.7824426219618442 / 3.4447904239400002  delayStats: 713ns / 3  responseStats: 0 / 1  timeoutStats: 0 / 1
 I0320 03:55:14.854877 les/serverpool.go:571] dialing 78de8a0916848093c73790ead81d1928bec737d565119932b98c6b100d944b7a95e94f847f689fc723399d2e31129d182f7ef3863f2b4c820abbf3ab2722344d@191.235.84.50:30303 out of 1, known: true
 I0320 03:55:14.855019 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *node.PrivateAdminAPI under 'admin'
 I0320 03:55:14.855040 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *node.PublicAdminAPI under 'admin'
 I0320 03:55:14.855093 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *debug.HandlerT under 'debug'
 I0320 03:55:14.855115 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *node.PublicDebugAPI under 'debug'
 I0320 03:55:14.855135 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *node.PublicWeb3API under 'web3'
 I0320 03:55:14.855160 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PublicCompilerAPI under 'eth'
 I0320 03:55:14.855178 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.CompilerAdminAPI under 'admin'
 I0320 03:55:14.855201 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PublicEthereumAPI under 'eth'
 I0320 03:55:14.855247 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PublicBlockChainAPI under 'eth'
 I0320 03:55:14.855213 p2p/dial.go:299] dial tcp 191.235.84.50:30303 (78de8a091684)
 I0320 03:55:14.855308 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PublicTransactionPoolAPI under 'eth'
 I0320 03:55:14.855321 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PublicTxPoolAPI under 'txpool'
 I0320 03:55:14.855339 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PublicDebugAPI under 'debug'
 I0320 03:55:14.855365 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PrivateDebugAPI under 'debug'
 I0320 03:55:14.855381 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PublicAccountAPI under 'eth'
 I0320 03:55:14.855425 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PrivateAccountAPI under 'personal'
 I0320 03:55:14.855456 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *les.LightDummyAPI under 'eth'
 I0320 03:55:14.855487 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *downloader.PublicDownloaderAPI under 'eth'
 I0320 03:55:14.855534 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *filters.PublicFilterAPI under 'eth'
 I0320 03:55:14.855556 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PublicNetAPI under 'net'
 I0320 03:55:14.855594 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *node.PrivateAdminAPI under 'admin'
 I0320 03:55:14.855612 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *node.PublicAdminAPI under 'admin'
 I0320 03:55:14.855653 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *debug.HandlerT under 'debug'
 I0320 03:55:14.855671 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *node.PublicDebugAPI under 'debug'
 I0320 03:55:14.855684 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *node.PublicWeb3API under 'web3'
 I0320 03:55:14.855703 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PublicCompilerAPI under 'eth'
 I0320 03:55:14.855721 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.CompilerAdminAPI under 'admin'
 I0320 03:55:14.855747 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PublicEthereumAPI under 'eth'
 I0320 03:55:14.855794 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PublicBlockChainAPI under 'eth'
 I0320 03:55:14.855849 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PublicTransactionPoolAPI under 'eth'
 I0320 03:55:14.855861 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PublicTxPoolAPI under 'txpool'
 I0320 03:55:14.855875 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PublicDebugAPI under 'debug'
 I0320 03:55:14.855889 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PrivateDebugAPI under 'debug'
 I0320 03:55:14.855902 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PublicAccountAPI under 'eth'
 I0320 03:55:14.855936 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PrivateAccountAPI under 'personal'
 I0320 03:55:14.855961 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *les.LightDummyAPI under 'eth'
 I0320 03:55:14.855980 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *downloader.PublicDownloaderAPI under 'eth'
 I0320 03:55:14.856009 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *filters.PublicFilterAPI under 'eth'
 I0320 03:55:14.856021 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PublicNetAPI under 'net'
 I0320 03:55:14.856139 node/node.go:341] IPC endpoint opened: /home/lash/.ethereum/geth.ipc
 I0320 03:55:16.954996 p2p/nat/nat.go:109] network port tcp:30303 could not be mapped: no UPnP or NAT-PMP router discovered
 I0320 03:55:16.969600 p2p/server.go:737] Added Peer 78de8a0916848093 191.235.84.50:30303
 I0320 03:55:16.969731 les/serverpool.go:165] connecting to 78de8a0916848093, state: 1
 I0320 03:55:16.969756 les/handler.go:313] Peer 78de8a0916848093 [les/1]: peer connected [Geth/v1.5.9-stable-a07539fb/linux/go1.7]
 I0320 03:55:18.042897 les/handler.go:339] LES: register peer 78de8a0916848093
 I0320 03:55:18.042950 les/fetcher.go:242] received announce from peer 78de8a0916848093  #3374100  a6aec54716c758e6  reorg: 0
 I0320 03:55:18.043352 les/serverpool.go:187] registered 78de8a0916848093c73790ead81d1928bec737d565119932b98c6b100d944b7a95e94f847f689fc723399d2e31129d182f7ef3863f2b4c820abbf3ab2722344d
 I0320 03:55:19.855467 les/odr.go:240] networkRequest  err = context deadline exceeded
 I0320 03:55:19.855509 internal/ethapi/api.go:578] call took 5.00009145s
 I0320 03:55:19.855525 contracts/release/release.go:134] Failed to retrieve current release: Missing trie node 0ceaf36085b50246f9654fcbaa3c8abfa4d0e5ea9f57df048dfab02159c26447
 I0320 03:55:34.848273 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1474] Quality of service: rtt 20s, conf 1.000, ttl 1m0s
```

... only output after this is new lines of QOS (also when using `--verbosity 6`

---

Is this expected behavior from these versions?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same hanging behavious with `geth` v1.5.9 .

I executed:

```
geth --light console
```

I also attached to the first instance to check out the methods you used:

```
geth attach
```

I found that I could not execute any commands in both consoles for the first ~ 10 minutes.

I had to break out of the first command console by pressing ^C 10 times.

I then restarted both commands again.

And the following command works:

```
> eth.getBalance("0x50dbed63da86ea1ca8c0bdce04d72228113be842")
591684102184704
```

I noticed that the synchronisation stopped at block 3,37.... while EtherScan.io was at block 3,38.... .

I exited the `geth --light console` console and restarted using the same command.

```
I0320 15:22:55.733141 core/headerchain.go:342] imported  192 headers in  31.112ms. #3383936 [2cde5f24… / 572d0c61…]
I0320 15:22:57.311638 core/headerchain.go:342] imported  192 headers in 250.223ms. #3384128 [d4bbf633… / 38dcd347…]
I0320 15:22:57.873056 core/headerchain.go:342] imported   13 headers in  20.722ms. #3384141 [a1373032… / b32e2eb6…]
> eth.blockNumber
3384141
> eth.syncing
false
> eth.getBalance("0x50dbed63da86ea1ca8c0bdce04d72228113be842")
970787901064008288
> I0320 15:23:20.291722 core/headerchain.go:342] imported    1 headers in   9.090ms. #3384142 [d6228133… / d6228133…]
```

This is the correct current balance for the account `0x50dbed63da86ea1ca8c0bdce04d72228113be842`.

Seems that the light client syncing has problems communicating with Ethereum nodes with the light client syncing.

The workaround is to restart several times when first light syncing.

---

#### Update

The `geth --light console` command prompt periodically hangs and my notebook fan starts spinning heavily.

As the following console message states:

```
I0320 15:30:28.698112 les/backend.go:191] WARNING: light client mode is an experimental feature
```

Searching `geth` outstanding issues with the keyword "light" shows up [12 issues](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20%20light), including an unresponsive console while the syncing is in progress.

You may want to wait until some of these issues are resolved and/or the light client mode comes out of experimental mode.

Comment: Thanks for this heads up. The latter attempt I was describing was using 1.5.9-stable from the release/1.5 branch. And using that it didn't even start syncing. So the behavior in this case is _not_ the same. I'm aware of the experimental status.